# What is the way proper way to manage Rails ActiveRecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, referential-integrity

I am new to Rails so bear with me…

I am trying to create a set of data related to 2 different models. I currently have the following models:

```
class M < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :u
 belongs_to :s
end

class U < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :m
 has_many :s, :through => m:
end

class S < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :m
 has_many :u, :through => m;
end
```

In the system, the user can create many Us and Ss. But when creating an M it should make sure that there exist a reference to an "u" and an "s".

I know i can do the following:

```
m1 = M.create()
u1.ms << m1
s1.ms << m1
```

Which has all the appropriate reference, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do either `one_u.s = one_s` or `one_s.u = one_u`.

According to [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), new `M` models will be managed by `ActiveRecord`. You can just set the attribute like a common `has_many` association, and the `M` rows will be created (and deleted) along with it.

Comment: I am confused. where is the reference m1 in your example? Do you mean:u1.s = s1? Since :s in U is a "has_many" collection, will assignment do the job?